# Just Created a Real Time Desktop notification for StackOverflow

Tags: support, desktop-notifications

I am Hari a software Engineer from India. I am a VB.net loving guy. 13 days before I thought to create a **desktop alert application for StackOverflow** which will help the experts to keep track of new questions in their respective interest area.

Now I completed it. It is fully functional. No login is required for this. It instantly pops the new questions on the desktop.

I need just one help. It is a free project and I want to make it available publicly to all. But I don't know how to promote it. Can anybody help me out to promote this product.

Any StackExchange members if you are seeing this message please help me to promote this product. I will be really glad if this product helps others.

Comment: Are you aware of http://stackapps.com/?

Comment: I see at least two similar apps: http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f and http://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-cross-platform-desktop-notification-app Is your app different / better?

Comment: My app is completely different from both of above and much effective also.

Comment: How do you poll Stack Overflow? I believe they are limiting plain requests to prevent server overload. The proper way is by using the API.

Comment: How they are limiting ? Is it per IP ? How much request one can send per hour ? I am using XMLs to read recent questions.